# Javascript click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a simple javascript function that will clone some html input fields when the user clicks a button, but for some reason the button's click function isn't being called when I click it. Any ideas why?

Here's the javascript:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){

        $("#default-label").hide();
        $("#default-element").hide();

        var counter = parseInt($("#counter").val());

        $("#addProduct").click(
            function(){

                var product = $('#fieldset-default');
                var newProduct = product.clone(true);
                newProduct.insertAfter(product);
                    document.getElementById("addProduct").innerHTML = 'Add More';
                    $("#counter").val(++counter);
            }
         );
    }
);
</script>
```

My HTML for the button:

```
<button id="addProduct" type="button" name="add">Add Product</button>
```

Comment: `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">`?  What is this, 1999?  It should be `<script type="text/javascript">` or in HTML5, just `<script>`.

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/3AzHQ/

Comment: Forgot to include jquery. My brain must still be on christmas vacation. thanks.

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LLRcP/ Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5YRum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you missed jquery plugin,included latest version of jquery library, if not there.